# Tenenbaum and Pollard, Ordinary Differential Equations, problem 1.4.18

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Tenenbaum and Pollard's "Ordinary Differential Equations," chapter 1, section 4, problem 18 asks for a differential equation whose solution is "

> A family of circles of fixed radii and centers on the $x$ axis.

**Solution.**
The family of circles of fixed radii $a$ and center $(h,0)$ is:

$f(x,y)=(x-h)^2+y^2-a^2=0\tag{a}$

If we write:

$y=g(x)=\sqrt{a^2-(x-h)^2}\tag{b}$ where $-a\le(x-h)\le{a}$

this defines $y$ as a function of $x$ on the interval $(h-a,h+a)$. Hence, $f$ defines $y$ as an implicit function of $x$ on the interval $(h-a,h+a)$.

Since, $(b)$ contains two constants, we assume it must be the solution of a second-order differential equation. Differentiating $(b)$ twice, we obtain,

$y'=\frac{-(x-h)}{\sqrt{a^2-(x-h)^2}}=\frac{-(x-h)}{y}\tag{c}$

$yy''+(y')^2=-1\tag{d}$

This must be the required differential equation.

My answer, however, does not match the one given in the text. The answer in the text is :

$(yy')^2+y^2=a^2$

I am guessing, my formulation of the solution is incorrect. Any inputs and help to solve this would be great!

Comment: The radius is fixed so there's only one parameter, not two.

Comment: Gotcha. I understand, thank you!